# Can't test HTTP status on MockMvc async REST service in spring-test 5.0.3 (works in 5.0.0)

Tags: java, spring, spring-test

I've generated fresh project using Spring Initializer (https://start.spring.io/)
Spring boot - 2.0.0.RC1 which ships spring in version 5.0.3.RELEASE.

Added the following controller:

```
@RestController
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/customer")
public class CustomerController {
    @GetMapping("/")
    public Future<ResponseEntity<String>> get1() {
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> new ResponseEntity<String ("not found", HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND));
    }
}
```

and having the following dependencies section in build.gradle (problem can be also replicated on maven build)

```
dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('org.springframework:spring-web')
    testCompile('org.springframework:spring-test')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

The following test fails:

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class CustomerControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void test404() throws Exception {
        MvcResult asyncResult = mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/customer/"))
                .andExpect(request().asyncStarted())
                .andReturn();

        mockMvc.perform(asyncDispatch(asyncResult))
                .andExpect(status().isNotFound());
    }
}
```

with the following log:

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = GET
      Request URI = /customer/
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = {}
             Body = null
    Session Attrs = {}

Handler:
             Type = com.example.wkicior.demo.CustomerController
           Method = public java.util.concurrent.Future<org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.String>> com.example.wkicior.demo.CustomerController.get1()

Async:
    Async started = true
     Async result = <404 Not Found,not found,{}>

Resolved Exception:
             Type = null

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 200
    Error message = null
          Headers = {}
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []

MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = GET
      Request URI = /customer/
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = {}
             Body = null
    Session Attrs = {}

Handler:
             Type = com.example.wkicior.demo.CustomerController
           Method = public java.util.concurrent.Future<org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.String>> com.example.wkicior.demo.CustomerController.get1()

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = null

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 200
    Error message = null
          Headers = {Content-Type=[text/plain;charset=UTF-8], Content-Length=[9]}
     Content type = text/plain;charset=UTF-8
             Body = not found
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []

java.lang.AssertionError: Status 
Expected :404
Actual   :200
```

It seems that the test sees status code as 200, not 404. The body content is returned properly, though.
What's interesting that downgrading to 5.0.0.RELEASE of spring-test - fixes the problem:

```
testCompile('org.springframework:spring-test:5.0.0.RELEASE')
```

Is this a spring-test bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like spring bug indeed: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-16430
moving to 5.0.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT resolves the problem